# 1612C codeforces algorithm timing out issue

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem: https://codeforces.com/contest/1612/submission/170114495

I've tested all the test cases that I could see in codeforces, but my code instantly gives the correct answers out. I'm not sure what kind of test cases is causing my code to take a long time to solve.

What I'm trying to do:
I've noticed that in any case of k, the total number of emotes displayed is k^2. Therefore, if k^2 < x, then the matter how big x is, the number of lines displayed will be 2k - 1. The first if-statement you see does exactly that.

Well what if the k^2 greater or equal than x? That is what I'm trying to do in the rest of the code. If k^2 is equal to x, well then it's just 2k -1. Easy.

What if k^2 is greater than x? I can start from 0 (stored in a variable called tempCount) and then add 1, 2, 3, etc. until I reach the limit x. The number of times I add the numbers to tempCount is the number of lines that will be displayed on the screen.

However, if k^2 is only a bit bigger than x, and both k and x are large numbers, it would be inefficient. For example, if k is 10000000 and x is 9999999999999, it would take a very long time to reach x. If I go backwards however, and start with tempCount = 2k-1 and subtract 1, 2, 3, etc., it would take much less time to find the answer. To determine if I should go forwards or backwards, I check if k^2 - x < k^2 / 2. If it's true, I start backwards, otherwise I start forwards.

The else statement nested in the else statement is to optimize the forward algorithm.

I still don't really know what is causing my algorithm to take a long time

Thanks for reading this, I know it's a lot.

Edit: adding code in here, didn't realize I can't link to external website

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int getNum(int current, int k) {
    if (current <= k) {
        return current;
    }
    return k - (current - k);
}

int main() { //next step to store the numbers processed into an array
    int t, tempK, tempCount = 0;
    unsigned long long tempX, tempTotal = 0, tempk0s = 0, tempx0s;
    std::vector<unsigned long long> x, k;

    std::cin >> t;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        std::cin >> tempK >> tempX;
        k.push_back(tempK);
        x.push_back(tempX);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < k.size(); i++) { //check if k^2 > x
        unsigned long long square = k[i] * k[i];
        if (k[i] <= x[i] && square <= x[i]) {
            std::cout << 2 * k[i] - 1 << std::endl;
        } else {
            long tempLimit = 2 * k[i] - 1;
            long long square = k[i] * k[i];
            unsigned long long quickCheck = (k[i] * (k[i] + 1)) / 2;
            if (k[i] <= x[i] && square > x[i] && square - x[i] < square / 2) {//check if I should start backwards
                while (square >= x[i] && square >= 0) {
                    tempCount++;
                    square -= tempCount;
                }
                tempCount = tempLimit - tempCount + 1;
            } else { //forwards algorithm
                if (x[i] == quickCheck) {
                    tempCount = k[i];
                } else if (x[i] > quickCheck) {//do I start from the middle?
                    tempTotal = quickCheck;
                    tempCount = k[i];
                    while (tempCount < tempLimit && tempTotal < x[i]) {
                        tempTotal += getNum(tempCount + 1, k[i]);
                        tempCount++;
                    }
                } else {//start at the beginning
                    while (tempCount < tempLimit && tempTotal < x[i]) {
                        tempTotal += getNum(tempCount + 1, k[i]);
                        tempCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
            std::cout << tempCount << std::endl;
        }
        tempCount = 0;
        tempTotal = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit 2: I changed my algorithm so that it used binary search and I'm still getting the timing out issue. Still not sure what kind of test cases are making my code run for so long...Adding the new code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
int getNum(int current, int k) {
    if (current <= k) {
        return current;
    }
    return k - (current - k);
}

int main() {
    int t, tempK, tempCount = 0;
    unsigned long long tempX;
    std::vector<unsigned long long> x, k;

    std::cin >> t;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        std::cin >> tempK >> tempX;
        k.push_back(tempK);
        x.push_back(tempX);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < k.size(); i++) {
        unsigned long long square = k[i] * k[i];
        if (square <= x[i]) {
            std::cout << 2 * k[i] - 1 << std::endl;
        } else {
            long long square = k[i] * k[i];
            long tempLine = k[i], temp = 1;
            long long tempEQTriangle = (tempLine - 1) * tempLine / 2, tempLength = 2 * k[i], maxDiv = log2(tempLength), tempLine2 = tempLine;
            bool less;
            if (x[i] <= tempEQTriangle) {
                less = true;
            } else {
                less = false;
            }
            while (!(x[i] > tempEQTriangle && x[i] <= tempEQTriangle + tempLine2)) {
                if (temp <= maxDiv) {
                    temp++;
                }

                if (x[i] > tempEQTriangle) {
                    if (temp >= maxDiv) {
                        tempLine++;
                    } else {
                        tempLine += tempLength / (int) pow(2, temp);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (temp >= maxDiv) {
                        tempLine--;
                    } else {
                        tempLine -= tempLength / (int) pow(2, temp);
                    }
                }
                if (less) {
                    tempEQTriangle = (tempLine - 1) * tempLine / 2;
                    tempLine2 = tempLine;
                } else {
                    tempEQTriangle = square - (tempLength + 1 - tempLine) * (tempLength - tempLine) / 2;
                    tempLine2 = getNum(tempLine, k[i]);
                }
            }
            tempCount = tempLine;
            std::cout << tempCount << std::endl;
        }
        tempCount = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried doing all the test cases with the binary search code and it runs really fast

Comment: Your code should be posted in your question and not as a link. See [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code)

Comment: You're also unlikely to get any help if you're unable to give us the information needed to reproduce the problem. a [mre] includes the data needed to reproduce the error condition.

Answer (score 1):

> If I go backwards however, and start with tempCount = 2k-1 and subtract 1, 2, 3, etc., it would take much less time to find the answer.

Generally speaking, if you have an `O(n)` iteration (where `n` is the number of elements), then irrespective of where you start (from the end, middle or top), the complexity will still work out to be `O(n)`. That's why your approach times out: you're using a linear search for each test case. Linearly iterating over `k` for `t` test cases would have a complexity of `O(t*k)`, which clearly times out.

Suggested fix: replace linear search with binary search. This will reduce the complexity to `O(t*log(k))`

Comment: Thanks, I previously saw the binary search tag next to the problem and I had no idea what it had to do with the problem. Will implement it!

Comment: Oh sorry, just got online. I tried implementing the binary search, but I'm getting the same timing out issue. I really don't know why it's not working...